# Removing float nan values from python list

Tags: python, string, list, nan

Context: I have converted a dataframe into lists, in order to prepare the data for a Market Basket Analysis. Each of the rows of the data frame is now a list. Each list has nan values and I want to condense the list down to just the non-nan values.

Original dataframe example

```
 Presc01            Presc02                    Presc03       Presc04  \
0         NaN                NaN                        NaN           NaN   
1  amlodipine  albuterol aerosol                allopurinol  pantoprazole   
2         NaN                NaN                        NaN           NaN   
3  citalopram            benicar  amphetamine salt combo xr           NaN   
4         NaN                NaN                        NaN           NaN
```

Every other row was blank, so I dropped it and re-indexed using:

```
df.dropna(subset = ["Presc01"], inplace=True)

df.index = range(len(df))
```

Then converted the rows into lists:

```
prescriptions = df.values.tolist()
```

an example of the 4th list:

```
in: print(prescriptions[3])
out:['paroxetine', 'allopurinol', nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan]
```

Then, I created a check to look at the datatypes within my list:

```
def checktype(prescriptions):
for element in prescriptions:
    if isinstance(element,int):
        print("Integer")
    if isinstance(element, str):
        print("String")
    if isinstance(element, float):
        print("Float")
```

And checked for the 4th row:

```
in: checktype(prescriptions[3]) 

out:String String Float Float Float Float Float Float Float Float Float Float Float Float Float Float Float Float Float Float
```

I have tried several methods posted online, using np.isnan, pd.isnull, variations of "for x if in x if x = x (or if x = not null, or if x =! 'nan')", etc, and I still cannot get them to go away.

TIA!

Comment: Update: I managed to get rid of my nan values for a single row by doing: prescriptions_clean8 = [item for item in prescriptions[8] if not (pd.isnull(item)) == True]. this only works for the 9th list though ([8]). how do i apply this to the entire list of lists?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this specific issue by combining all the columns together, and re-splitting them into lists. the nan's were eliminated in the new lists.